# TypeLits or Singletons: Promoting an `Integer` to `KnownNat` (`Nat`) at Runtime

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, dependent-type, singleton-type

I've found two ways to promote an Integer to a Nat (or KnownNat, I don't get the distintion yet) at runtime, either using TypeLits and Proxy (Data.Proxy and GHC.TypeLits), or Singletons (Data.Singletons). In the code below you can see how each of the two approaches is used:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}

module Main where

import Prelude hiding (replicate)
import Data.Proxy (Proxy(Proxy))
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import Data.Singletons (SomeSing(..), toSing)
import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Singletons.TypeLits
import Data.Vector.Sized (Vector, replicate)

main :: IO ()
main = playingWithTypes 8

playingWithTypes :: Integer -> IO ()
playingWithTypes nn = do

  case someNatVal nn of
    Just (SomeNat (proxy :: Proxy n)) -> do
--      let (num :: Integer) = natVal proxy
--      putStrLn $ "Some num: " <> show num
      putStrLn $ "Some vector: " <> show (replicate 5 :: Vector n Int)
    Nothing -> putStrLn "There's no number, the integer was not a natural number"

  case (toSing nn :: SomeSing Nat) of
    SomeSing (SNat :: Sing n) -> do
--      let (num :: Integer) = natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)
--      putStrLn $ "Some num: " <> show num
      putStrLn $ "Some vector: " <> show (replicate 5 :: Vector n Int)
```

The documentation for [TypeLits](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html) indicates that it shouldn't be used by developers, but Singletons don't capture the case in which the given Integer is not a natural number (i.e., running `playingWithTypes 8` runs without errors, but `playingWithTypes (-2)` fails when we try to create a Singleton from the non-natural number).

So, what is the "standard" way to promote an `Integer` to a `Nat`? Or what is the best approach to promote, using TypeLits and Proxy, or Singletons?

Comment: I'm confused.  Do you want `playingWithTypes (-2)` to *succeed*?

Comment: @luqui Well `playingWithTypes` receives an Integer, and this Integer could be either natural or negative, therefore I wold expect it doesn't just dies at runtime if I send it the wrong value. Is for this reason that I would prefer using `someNatVal` over `toSing`, `someNatVal` is more explicit about its impossibility in converting all `Integer`s into `Nat`s while I need to add some non-obvious code `toSing` to not let it die suddenly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `Nat` (or `KnownNat`, I don't get the distintion yet)

`Nat` is the kind of type-level natural numbers. It has no term-level inhabitants. The idea is that GHC promotes any natural number into the type-level, and gives it kind `Nat`.

`KnownNat` is a constraint, on something of kind `Nat`, whose implementation witnesses how to convert the thing of kind `Nat` to a term-level `Integer`. GHC automagically creates instances of `KnownNat` for *all* type-level inhabitants of the kind `Nat`<sup>1</sup>.

That said, even if every `n :: Nat` (read type `n` of kind `Nat`) has a `KnownNat` instance on it<sup>1</sup>, you still need to write out the constraint.

> I've found two ways to promote an `Integer` to a `Nat`

Have you really? At the end of the day, `Nat` in today's GHC is simply magical. `singletons` taps into that same magic. Under the hood, it [uses `someNatVal`](https://github.com/goldfirere/singletons/blob/fe370c4a26088cac370a14dc6be342194103f131/src/Data/Singletons/TypeLits/Internal.hs#L66-L70).

> So, what is the "standard" way to promote an `Integer` to a `Nat`? Or what is the best approach to promote, using `GHC.TypeLits` and `Proxy`, or singletons?

There is no standard way. My take is: use `singletons` when you can afford its dependency footprint and `GHC.TypeLits` otherwise. The advantage of `singletons` is that the `SingI` type class makes it convenient to do induction based analysis while still also relying on GHC's special `Nat` type.

---

<sup>1</sup> As pointed out in the comments, not *every* inhabitant of the `Nat` kind has a `KnownNat` instance. For example, `Any Nat :: Nat` where `Any` is the [one from `GHC.Exts`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#t:Any). Only the inhabitants `0`, `1`, `2`, ... have `KnownNat` instances.

Comment: How does `SingI` help with induction? For induction, Peano naturals (whether from `singletons` or not) work more naturally than `TypeLits` ones. For the latter, you can fake up an eliminator `elimNat :: f 0 -> (forall k. SingI k => f k -> f (k + 1)) -> Sing n -> f n` using `unsafeCoerce`, but everything is awkward.

Comment: @dfeuer Wait, aren't `Nat`s from `singletons` and from `TypeLits` the same? Do `singletons` support `Nat`s and "peano Nats"?

Comment: @helq, yes, those are the same. Sorry, got confused. I meant `singleton-nats`.

Comment: Not *every* `n :: Nat` has `KnownNat` instance.  An empty `type family A :: Nat` will give you a "nonstandard" natural at the type level.